# Prove that $\beta$ is a basis for $F^n$ if and only if $\det(B)$ is not zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\beta=\{u_1,u_2, \cdots ,u_n\}$ be a subset of $F^n$ containing $n$ distinct vectors, and let $B$ be the matrix in $\mathsf{M}_{n\times n}(F)$ having $u_j$ as column $j$. Prove that $\beta$ is a basis for $F^n$ if and only if $\det(B)$ is not zero.

This is what I tried to prove 'if' part.
Let c be a row vector of scalars, $\{c_1, c_2, \cdots , c_n\}$, and consider the equation $Bc=0$.
Since $\beta$ is a basis of an $n$-dimensional space, its $n$ vectors are linearly independent, so $c=0$.
(i.e. $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n=0$)
So $Ker(B)=0$
Since $B$ is a map from $F^n$ to $F^n$, $B$ is invertible. So $\det B$ is not zero.

I tried 'only if' part, but I could not. Can I get some help?

Comment: If $b$ is not a basis, then the columns are linearly dependent.  Thus you can express one column in terms of the others.  This dependence relation can be expressed in terms of a column vector (not row vector) being in the kernel.  the equation $Bc=0$ demands that $c$ be a column vector,)

Answer (score 1):

If $\det B \neq 0$ then $B$ is invertible and, for any vector $\vec{y}$ there exists a vector $\vec{x}$ such that $\vec{y} = B\vec{x}$ (this $\vec{x}$ is given by $B^{-1}\vec{y}$, but that is irrelevant). Then, notice that 
$$
\vec{y} = B\vec{x} = x_1\vec{u}_1 + x_2\vec{u}_2 + \cdots + x_n\vec{u}_n
$$
where $x_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of the vector $\vec{x}$. Thus our set $\beta$ of vectors $\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2\cdots\vec{u}_n$ spans the space. Since the cardinality of $\beta$ is the same as the dimension of the vector space, it follows that $\beta$ is a basis.